# can we publish a stream more then once?

Tags: java, project-reactor

All the following codes don't print anything. Why?

```
ConnectableFlux<Integer> publish = Flux.just(1)
        .publish();

ConnectableFlux<Integer> publish1 = Flux.just(2)
        .flatMap(x -> publish)
        .publish();

publish1.subscribe(System.out::println, System.out::println, System.out::println);
publish1.connect();
```

---

```
ConnectableFlux<Integer> publish1 = Flux.just(2)
        .publish()
        .publish();

publish1.subscribe(System.out::println, System.out::println, System.out::println);
publish1.connect();
```

---

```
ConnectableFlux<Integer> publish1 = Flux.just(2)
        .publish()
        .doOnNext(System.out::println)
        .publish();

publish1.subscribe(System.out::println, System.out::println, System.out::println);
publish1.connect();
```

Comment: A stream is consumed after it is used.

Comment: Thats how `connectableFlux` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Do not forget to give a `.connect`ion for every `ConnectableFlux`

In all of those examples, there is missed `.connect`ion statement.

For the first case, to make it working we have to `.connect` to first `publish` `ConnectableFlux` as well:

```
ConnectableFlux<Integer> publish = Flux.just(1)
        .publish();

ConnectableFlux<Integer> publish1 = Flux.just(2)
        .flatMap(x -> publish)
        .publish();

publish1.subscribe(System.out::println, System.out::println, System.out::println);
publish1.connect();
publish.connect();
```

For the two following examples, we have something similar. When we use `Flux.just(...).publish().publish()` we create two `ConnectableFlux`. The problem here is that the first one is erased. In case if it is mandatory to have subsequent `.publish`ing (which is quite illogical) we may use following technique to avoid erasing of previous `ConnectableFlux`es:

```
ConnectableFlux<Integer> publish1 = Flux.just(2)
        .publish()
        .autoConnect() // or .autoConnect(0)
        .doOnNext(System.out::println)
        .publish();

publish1.subscribe(System.out::println, System.out::println, System.out::println);
publish1.connect();
```

In that example we use the `.autoConnect()` operator which in case of `.autoConnect(0)` is just combination of `ConnectableFlux#connect` and `return this;` statements. In case of `.autoConnect(>0)` is used some lazy subscription to the initial source which sounds like "*Connect to the initial source when and only when we got **N** subscribers*"

Comment: Excellent! Thanks agian Oleh:)